# OpsCenter with HTTPS kills session when clicked on Spark Console

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have a DataStax Enterprise cluster running on 2 AWS nodes. DSE is installed in enterprise mode and one of the nodes is configured in Analytics mode.

Everything was working normal until I followed the steps outlined here to enable HTTPS for OpsCenter: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscEnablingAuth.html

OpsCenter authentication is now working fine. However if I click the Spark Console hyperlink of the Analytics node the raw text of the Spark job details will show but the page's CSS and images are gone, looking at Chrome's developer tools it looks like I'm getting an access denied on these resources. Also, as soon as I click the link and the Spark Console popup opens, the OpsCenter tab will kill my session and log me out. I was able to observe the same behavior with Chrome and IE.

Instance: m3.large
AMI: DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.6.3-1404-hvm - ami-8b392cbb

Answer (score 3):

I've reproduced this issue using OpsCenter 5.2 and DSE 4.7.  I've created a ticket in our internal tracking system to address this issue; the reference number for that ticket is OPSC-6606.

Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention!